# Must Objective-C messages have split up names to have different arguments?

Tags: objective-c

That's an example

```
- (NSArray *)shipsAtPoint:(CGPoint)bombLocation withDamage:(BOOL)damaged;
```

May we delete withDamage part here? What's the difference if that's available?

Comment: Note that you can have a single keyword that accepts multiple parameters, in a comma-separated list.  This is pretty much identical to standard C/C++ conventions, other than the different decoration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually can, and then you would call the method like this:

```
[obj shipsAtPoint:point :YES];
```

But it's considered bad style and virtually no one does this.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about that point, but I thought that it must have a reason too :)